# Shopware 6 | How to add cms element in cloud app?

Tags: cloud, content-management-system, shopware6

i'm developing an Cloud App for Shopware Community-Store including a new CMS-Block and -Element which i need to add a code snippet.

I found ways to add new blocks, but nothing for cms elements.

So my question is how to add cms elements in an cloud app? Is there any documentation probably?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

At the moment it's not possible to create CMS-Elements within the app-system. The only thing you can do right now is a CMS-Block.

The CMS-Elements will come soon with the admin SDK. Take a look here: [CMS-Element](https://shopware.github.io/admin-extension-sdk/docs/guide/api-reference/cms/registerCmsElement/)

Edit:
Since 6.4.17.0 it is possible to create CMS elements in the app system.

The Admin SDK doc is here https://shopware.github.io/admin-extension-sdk/docs/guide/api-reference/cms/registerCmsElement/

Here is the corresponding doc you need as well: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/content/cms/add-cms-element-via-admin-sdk